# How to send email using ssmtp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gmail, ssmtp

I am attempting to write a script which send emails containing log messages...

Firstly, I have installed `ssmtp` and configured `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` as follows:

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=myname@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# The address where the mail appears to come from for user authentication.
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname.  Must be correctly formed, fully qualified domain name or GMail will reject connection.
hostname=ananas

# Use SSL/TLS before starting negotiation
TLS_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
UseTLS=Yes
UseSTARTTLS=Yes

# Username/Password
AuthUser=myname@gmail.com
AuthPass=mypassword
AuthMethod=LOGIN

# Email 'From header's can override the default domain?
FromLineOverride=yes
```

Then I tried to send me a test mail

```
user@ananas:~$ echo -e 'Subject: test\n\nTesting ssmtp' | sendmail -v myname@gmail.com
[<-] 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP v20sm16357528wra.19 - gsmtp
[->] EHLO ananas
[<-] 250 SMTPUTF8
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
[->] EHLO ananas
[<-]
sendmail:  (ananas)
```

I haven't received any mail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssmtp` is nearly to be no longer supported. I tried to use the suggested package `msmtp`, and it works